# Insert image (Byte[]) into word doc using XSLT & C#

Tags: c#, xslt, arrays, xslcompiledtransform

I have an xml document that looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Job>
       <ID>1</ID>
       <Name>Front Window<Name>
       <Image>/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQ..(etc)</windowImage>
    </job>
    <Job>
       <ID>2</ID>
       <Name>BackWindow<Name>
       <Image>/9j/4BAQSkZJRgABAQ..(etc)</windowImage>
    </job>
</xml>
```

Also a XSLT file which loops through each job. My problem is how can I insert the images which are saved as byte[]? They are only saved in the database and no file is created for them because they are generated in the application. My C# code looks like this.

```
Job jobClass = new ReportSQL().createXMLclass(_jobID);
new ReportSQL().createXMLFile(jobClass);
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load(@"Code\quoteTemplate.xslt");
xslt.Transform("xmlfile.xml", "doc.doc");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the XML you want to produce saves the images as text. This can be accomplished by encoding the bytearray as Base64:

```
String s = Convert.ToBase64String(byte[])
```

and

```
byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String(String)
```

Comment: it already produces them a string. I want to know how to display the string as an image in a word doc using openXML

Comment: maybe as an data url in an image? In HTML you can do <img src="data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQ..(etc)"/>